# What exactly do --limit 1/s and --limit-burst mean in iptables rules?

Tags: centos, iptables, redhat, icmp

I'm using CentOS 5.x  trying to wrap my mind around the following iptables rule on one of my servers:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
```

On another server I have:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 3 -j ACCEPT
```

I understand that both of these rules are designed to allow (and throttle) incoming ping requests but what is the `limit-burst` option about?  And are these allowances on a per host basis? Or do they apply to any/all incoming ICMP connections at all?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The math is fully explained [in the netfilter docs](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html), but it's reasonable to say that the `limit-burst` argument specifies the number of matches that are allow through before the `limit` of 1 per second "kicks in". These two rules both apply only to ICMP echo request packets (incoming PING requests). These are not per-host limits and apply to anything the rule matches (which, in this case, would be all ICMP echo requests).

Comment: So for the second rule, it will allow up to 3 icmp echo request packets (no matter how quickly they're received) and then only allow 1 icmp packet per second after that (regardless of which host the request is coming from)?  At what point does iptables "reset" and allow a burst of up to three packets again?

Comment: It's a token bucket. The bucket starts w/ 3 tokens in it, and a token is removed for each ICMP echo-request that is received. For each  1 second of no ICMP echo requests 1 token is added to the bucket until the bucket reaches 3 tokens again, where it stays until it receives more ICMP echo requests.

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I needed to know. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 8):

`--limit`: Specifies the rate at what tokens get refilled into the bucket. `4/hour` means 4 tokens per hour (1 token every 15 minutes).

`--limit-burst`: Specifies the maximum amount of tokens that can be filled in the bucket. (This is also the amount of tokens the bucket starts out with).

Answer (score 1):

I read both answers, but the actual `man itables-extensions` made me grok it:

> ### limit
>
> This module matches at a limited rate using a token bucket filter.  A rule using this extension will match until this limit is reached.  It can be used in combination with the LOG target to give limited logging, for example.
>
> xt_limit has no negation support - you will have to use `-m hashlimit !  --hashlimit` rate in this case whilst omitting --hashlimit-mode.
>
> - `--limit rate[/second|/minute|/hour|/day]` -- Maximum average matching rate: specified as a number, with an optional `/second`, `/minute`, `/hour`, or `/day` suffix; the default is 3/hour.
> - `--limit-burst number` -- Maximum initial number of packets to match: this number gets recharged by one every time the limit specified above is not reached, up to this number; the default is 5.